Implementing Livewire navigation with Laravel email verification notice
I'm building a SPA using Laravel Livewire. When I'm trying to implement the email notification according to the Laravel documentation, the route should look like this:
Route::get('/email/verify', function () {
    return view('auth.verify-email');
})->name('verification.notice');

However, I'd like to use the SPA way to execute this task. Is there any other way to force the route executed by the SPA method (using wire:navigate)?
